# How to convert columns to rows in excel vba based on column condition

Tags: vba, excel

Input:

a   1   2   3
b   1   2   3
c   1   2   3

a   1   16  17
b   12  15  16
c   13  14  17

I have this kind of data in my excel .From this I want see my required output as below with help of vba script.

Required op:

a   b   c
1   1   1
2   2   2
3   3   3
1   12  13
16  15  14
17  16  17

Thanks In advance.

Comment: It looks like you're converting rows to columns.  I would create an array an use `WorksheetFunction.Transpose` to flip it's dimensions but you can also use `Range().Copy` with `Range().PasteSpecial Transpose:=True`.  If you run into problems post your code and I'll be happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

Here I am exploiting the facts the `For Each` iterates over a 2D array column by column and ranges fill row by row to transpose the data.

---

[image]

```
Sub JustPlayingAround()
    Dim arArea, v
    Dim rArea As Range, rSource As Range, rDestination As Range
    Dim x As Long
    Set rSource = Range("A1", Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    Set rDestination = Range("H1").Resize(1, 3)

    For Each rArea In rSource.Areas
        For Each v In rArea.Value
            x = x + 1
            rDestination(x) = v
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply but Here ,am getting individual sets of data by having headers in between splited data .But my requirement is to have ,clubbed data by having only single header on top rows like as below    a b c
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
1 12 13
16 15 14
17 16 17

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply but Here ,am getting individual sets of data by having headers in between splited data .But my requirement is to have ,clubbed data by having only single header on top rows like as below        
a b c
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
1 12 13
16 15 14                                                                                                                            17 16 17

Comment: @TSurendra My new answer meets your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
Sub TransposeData()
    Const FirstHeader As String = "a"
    Dim arCurrent, arAll
    Dim lastRow As Long, x As Long, xAll As Long, y As Long
    Dim firstAddress As String
    Dim c As Range

    With Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(1)
        lastRow = .Rows(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set c = .Find(FirstHeader, After:=.Rows(Rows.Count), LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            ReDim arAll(lastRow, c.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count - 1)
            firstAddress = c.Address
            Do
                arCurrent = c.CurrentRegion.Value2
                If IsArray(arCurrent) Then
                    arCurrent = Application.Transpose(arCurrent)

                    For x = IIf(x = 0, 1, 2) To UBound(arCurrent, 1)
                        For y = 1 To UBound(arCurrent, 2)
                            arAll(xAll, y - 1) = arCurrent(x, y)
                        Next
                        xAll = xAll + 1
                    Next
                End If
                Set c = .FindNext(c)
            Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress
        End If
    End With
    Worksheets.Add
    Range("A1").Resize(xAll + 1, UBound(arAll, 2) + 1) = arAll

End Sub
```